# Draw Curve Text With Center Alignment : iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

Here I want to archive a text in circular shape with center alignment.

Here is what I have achieved so far

[image]

**Now here Test1 and Test2 are starting from the beginning from the path. I want this to display from center of path.**

Here is the code to draw text on path.

```
- (void) drawAttributedString: (NSAttributedString *) string
{
    if (!string) return;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (context == NULL) COMPLAIN_AND_BAIL(@"No context to draw into", nil);
    if (self.elements.count < 2) return;

    // Keep a running tab of how far the glyphs have traveled to
    // be able to calculate the percent along the point path
    float glyphDistance = 0.0f;
    float lineLength = self.pathLength;

    for (int loc = 0; loc < string.length; loc++)
    {
        // Retrieve item
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(loc, 1);
        NSAttributedString *item = [string attributedSubstringFromRange:range];

        // Start halfway through each glyph
        CGRect bounding = [item boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:0 context:nil];
        glyphDistance += bounding.size.width /2;

        // Find point
        CGPoint slope;
        CGFloat percentConsumed = glyphDistance / lineLength;
        CGPoint targetPoint = [self pointAtPercent:percentConsumed withSlope:&slope];

        // Accommodate the forward progress
        glyphDistance += bounding.size.width / 2;
        if (percentConsumed >= 1.0f) break;

        // Calculate the rotation
        float angle = atan(slope.y / slope.x); //  + M_PI;
        if (slope.x < 0) angle += M_PI; // going left, update the angle

        // Draw the glyph
        PushDraw(^{
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, targetPoint.x, targetPoint.y);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, angle);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -bounding.size.width / 2, -item.size.height / 2);
            [item drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        });
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you've already written the code to draw the text (though I don't know what "PushDraw" is). What problem do you have?

Comment: If you see the picture.. I draw border also ( Black and Green Line )... Text is starting from the begining of the border... I want text in center align..

Comment: I've some code that draws text along a path inside SVGgh https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh  see  addGlyphsToContex  although that might be too much to include in your project. (I would actually draw things like this by creating an SVG template, inserting the dynamic strings, and give that to an SVG rendering library to draw).